# UISwipegesture not working with UITableview

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignTextView)];    
         swipeGestureRecognizer.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        swipeGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    [self.tableview addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];


-(void)resignTextView
{
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I do not know Why resignTextView method not get called?

Comment: is tableview user interaction enabled? if not, set it and try'

Comment: it is enabled.sometimes it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tableview has a scrollview and you can get the delegates of it to get the scroll events.

Check the docs for the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, and implement the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` or `-scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` methods as appropriate to your situation.

Just implement the methods and it works since the tableview delegates implements the underlying scroll delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding Swipe Gesture on Table View and in Downword direction. As you know Table View already has a Scroll and it scrolls upward and downward direction. If you add a Swipe Gesture in Downward direction. Then every time when you swipe in downward direction calls scroll methods of scroll and table moves scroll and device layer detect no swipe action, so ur method not called. In a very few situation when sometime there is less cell and table is not scrolling then try to check it again ur swipe method get called. Both swipe in downward direction and scrolling are not works properly in simultaneously.

Comment: what u actually want to do ??  can u explain.

Comment: I need like default Messages app

Comment: sorry. need more explanation

Answer (score 0):

you missed `：` after resignTextView